# Как использовать псевдоним (алиас) в шаблоне LIKE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, like, alias

коллеги!

Вопрос про вот такой SQL-запрос:

```
    $tmpSQL = 'SELECT `pcab_business`.`ID` as "anonym_id", `pcab_business`.`business_name` as "anonym_name", `pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id` as "category_id", ';
    $tmpSQL .= ' (SELECT `pcab_categories`.`category_name` FROM `pcab_categories` WHERE `pcab_categories`.`ID`=`pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id`) as "category_name", ';
    $tmpSQL .= ' (SELECT `pcab_projectmeta`.`project_id` FROM `pcab_projectmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "anonim_professional_project" AND `meta_value` LIKE "%anonym_id%") as "project_id" ';
    $tmpSQL .= ' FROM `pcab_business` LEFT JOIN `pcab_categories4businesses` ON `pcab_business`.`ID`= `pcab_categories4businesses`.`business_id` WHERE `user_id` = 0 ';
```

На выходе (то, что передается БД) получается:

```
SELECT `pcab_business`.`ID` as "anonym_id", `pcab_business`.`business_name` as "anonym_name", `pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id` as "category_id",  (SELECT `pcab_categories`.`category_name` FROM `pcab_categories` WHERE `pcab_categories`.`ID`=`pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id`) as "category_name",  (SELECT `pcab_projectmeta.`project_id` FROM `pcab_projectmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "anonim_professional_project" AND `meta_value` LIKE "%anonym_id%")  FROM `pcab_business` LEFT JOIN `pcab_categories4businesses` ON `pcab_business`.`ID`= `pcab_categories4businesses`.`business_id` WHERE `user_id` = 0
```

А мне надо, чтобы в LIKE "%anonim_id%" подставлялось значение из SELECT `pcab_business`.`ID` as "**anonym_id**" - то есть id из текущей строки.

Буду признателен за совет, куда копать. Гугл, к сожалению, рассказывает про алиасы, но без применения их в шаблоне LIKE.

Comment: Прошу не смеяться: Я попробовал запросить ChatGPT! И он даже ответил, и почти разумно. Порекомендовал CONCAT("%", pcab_business.ID, "%") в LIKE - вот только в его версии ошибка "Запрос возвращает больше одной записи" - хотя по бизнес-логике такого быть не может, каждый anonym_id только с одним project_id связан.

Comment: *Вопрос про вот такой SQL-запрос* Это не SQL запрос. Это PHP код, который его собирает. Выложите именно собранный текст запроса. PS. В MySQL используется три типа кавычек, и каждый строго для своих целей. Лепить в запрос не какой нужно в данном месте, а какой под руку подвернулся - прямой путь к проблемам.

Comment: *хотя по бизнес-логике такого быть не может, каждый anonym_id только с одним project_id связан* Бизнес-логика вовсе даже не гарантирует целостности данных. Более того, если нет поддержки бизнес-логики со стороны структуры БД  (в данном случае - соответствующего уникального индекса), то появление противоречащих бизнес-логике ошибок в данных - всего лишь вопрос времени...

Answer (score 3):

Если почистить запрос от PHP-кода и отформатировать его, получится

```sql
SELECT `pcab_business`.`ID` as "anonym_id", 
       `pcab_business`.`business_name` as "anonym_name", 
       `pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id` as "category_id",
       ( SELECT `pcab_categories`.`category_name` 
         FROM `pcab_categories` 
         WHERE `pcab_categories`.`ID`=`pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id`
         ) as "category_name", 
       ( SELECT `pcab_projectmeta`.`project_id` 
         FROM `pcab_projectmeta` 
         WHERE `meta_key` LIKE "anonim_professional_project" 
           AND `meta_value` LIKE "%anonym_id%"
         ) as "project_id" 
FROM `pcab_business` 
LEFT JOIN `pcab_categories4businesses` 
    ON `pcab_business`.`ID`= `pcab_categories4businesses`.`business_id` 
WHERE `user_id` = 0;
```

Так сразу видны ошибки.

Первая - идеологическая. Сравнение двух строковых значений выполняется оператором сравнения `=`, а не оператором проверки на соответствие шаблону `LIKE`.

Вторая - использование двойных кавычек для квотирования имён объектов. Кстати, в запросе вообще нет имён, требующих квотирования.

Третья - использование алиаса выходного поля в подзапросе.

Если исправить, получится

```sql
SELECT pcab_business.ID as anonym_id, 
       pcab_business.business_name as anonym_name, 
       pcab_categories4businesses.category_id as category_id,
       ( SELECT pcab_categories.category_name 
         FROM pcab_categories 
         WHERE pcab_categories.ID = pcab_categories4businesses.category_id
         ) as category_name, 
       ( SELECT pcab_projectmeta.project_id 
         FROM pcab_projectmeta 
         WHERE meta_key = 'anonim_professional_project'
           AND meta_value = pcab_business.ID
         ) as project_id 
FROM pcab_business 
LEFT JOIN pcab_categories4businesses 
    ON pcab_business.ID = pcab_categories4businesses.business_id 
WHERE user_id = 0;
```

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение по скобкам, К сожалению, приведенный вариант не подходит. Оператор LIKE %% использовался потому, что надо было найти упоминание цифрового id в ряде строчных значений. Вот пример одного из значений поля [["54","34","0"],["40","44","0"],["37","37","0"]] - и надо найти запись в таблице, в которой в строке упоминается anonym_id (например, 40). При проверке предложенного Вами очищенного варианта я получил серию " Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '[["54","34","0"],["40","44","0"],["37","37","0"]]'" , а весь столбец project_id имеет значение NULL.

Comment: @Vit *Вот пример одного из значений поля `[["54","34","0"],["40","44","0"],["37","37","0"]]`* Так это ж массив массивов JSON! Соответственно для связывания надо использовать соответствующие JSON-функции. *Оператор LIKE %% использовался потому, что надо было найти упоминание цифрового id в ряде строчных значений.* Ну так твой `LIKE '%4%'` на это значение откликнется бодрым TRUE, хотя именно значения `4` нет и в помине.

Answer (score 0):

@Akina, еще раз спасибо за рекомендации. В итоге ChatGPT со своей идеей насчет CONCAT победил. То есть, используя его идею и подкорректировав паттерн запроса, я получил искомый результат.
Теперь запрос выглядит вот так:

```
SELECT `pcab_business`.`ID` as anonym_id, `pcab_business`.`business_name` as anonym_name, `pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id` as category_id,  (SELECT `pcab_categories`.`category_name` FROM `pcab_categories` WHERE `pcab_categories`.`ID`=`pcab_categories4businesses`.`category_id`) as category_name,  (SELECT `pcab_projectmeta`.`project_id` FROM `pcab_projectmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "anonim_professional_project" AND `meta_value` LIKE CONCAT('%["', anonym_id, '",%')) as project_id FROM `pcab_business` LEFT JOIN `pcab_categories4businesses` ON `pcab_business`.`ID`= `pcab_categories4businesses`.`business_id` WHERE `user_id` = 0
```

P.S. А заодно нашел ошибку и в той самой бизнес-логике, и внес исправление в кусок кода, который на малой выборке тестов отработал правильно. Черт, как же не хочется признавать, что AI помог!! ))))